# Validate BIN Numbers in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Once a user gives me their credit card type and their credit card number I'd like to display an error toast message if the number and card type don't match up, per their BIN: https://www.bincodes.com/bin-list/

The code below produces the toast message when selecting "American Express" and entering a number whether that number starts with 34 or 37 or any other numbers.

```js
switch ($scope.newPayment.card_type) {
  case "American Express":
    $scope.digits = $scope.newPayment.card_number.toString().substr(0, 2).valueOf();
    if ($scope.digits != 34 || $scope.digits != 37) {

      toastr.error('Card number does not match card type');
      return;
    }
    break;
  case "Visa":
    $scope.digits = $scope.newPayment.card_number.toString().substr(0, 1).valueOf();
    if ($scope.digits != 4) {

      toastr.error('Card number does not match card type');
      return;
    }
    break;
  case "Mastercard":
    $scope.digits = $scope.newPayment.card_number.toString().substr(0, 2).valueOf();
    if (51 > $scope.digits > 55) {

      $scope.digits = $scope.newPayment.card_number.toString().substr(0, 4).valueOf();
      if (2221 > $scope.digits > 2720) {

        toastr.error('Card number does not match card type');
        return;
      }
    }
    break;
  case "Discover":
    $scope.digits = $scope.newPayment.card_number.toString().substr(0, 4).valueOf();
    if ($scope.digits != 6011) {

      $scope.digits = $scope.newPayment.card_number.toString().substr(0, 2).valueOf();
      if ($scope.digits != 65) {

        $scope.digits = $scope.newPayment.card_number.toString().substr(0, 3).valueOf();
        if (644 > $scope.digits > 649) {

          $scope.digits = $scope.newPayment.card_number.toString().substr(0, 6).valueOf();
          if (622126 > $scope.digits > 622925) {

            toastr.error('Card number does not match card type');
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    break;
  default:
}
```

Comment: Be more descriptive of what "isn't working" means.  Are you getting an error?  What is it *actually* doing?  Have you followed the code in a debugger?

Comment: @Amy I haven't been able to follow it on a debugger - this is the first time I've worked in Javascript. I restructured the code to test the case statement, toast message and $scope.digits value. When one of the card types is chosen a toast message appears with the clipped $scope.digits value. My assumption is there is a problem with the "$scope.digits != 34 " evaluations.

Comment: Using a debugger is an *essential* programming skill.  I highly recommend you poke at this yourself in the debugger.  I prefer the Chrome debugging tools to any other browsers, but YMMV.  Hit F12 to launch your dev tools, go to the Source tab, and find your JavaScript file.  Set a breakpoint, trigger the code, and trace through it line by line.

Answer (score 1):

My test case was on the one broken line of code.

```
if ($scope.digits != 34  || $scope.digits != 37 ){
```

will always be true as a number cannot simultaneously be 34 and 37.

I updated this and am good to go.